# What is the difference between Keras and tf.keras in TensorFlow 1.1+?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Now that TensorFlow 1.1 supports the Keras API under `tf.contrib.keras`, which one should I use if I intend to use Keras with a TF backend?

Is the `tf.contrib.keras` version different in any way than a regular Keras distribution? (TF specific optimizations of internal data structures come to mind). Is there any benefit in terms of using Keras and TensorFlow Core together if I use one or the other?

Or is `tf.contrib.keras` simply a copy of the same codebase as Keras but under a different namespace?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> > > If there will be two github repositories, how would you sync pull
> > >       requests to tf.keras and this repository? Will there be someone
> > >       applying changes in one repositority to another?
>
> The codebases will be different, so there will be no need to replicate
>   pull requests. For API changes, you would send a PR to the API spec
>   itself, and changes to the API spec would be replicated across all
>   codebases.

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5299#issuecomment-278166426

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though. If I want to use the TF backend, concretely should I `import tf.contrib.keras` or `import keras`?

Comment: Still feel confused. if the API are in sync, does that mean these two lib are the same to end user?

Answer (score 29):

`tf.keras` (formerly `tf.contrib.keras`) is an implementation of keras 2 implemented exclusively with/for tensorflow. It is hosted on the tensorflow repo and has a distinct code base than the official repo (the last commit there in the `tf-keras` branch [dates back from May 2017](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/tf-keras)).

As a rule of thumb, if your code use any tensorflow-specific code,  say anything in `tf.data.*` for providing inputs or `tf.summary.*` for visualization in tensorboard, it is simpler to just use `tf.keras`. (Some may even recommend *not* using the reference Keras implementation with TF because of [occasional problems it has with this toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51167542/1735003)).

On the other hand, if you plan to actively maintain a framework-agnostic code, using keras' own package is your only choice.

If you don't care much about being framework-agnostic but don't use tensorflow-specific code, I would probably advise to go with `tf.keras` and start using tensorflow-specific code, esp. `tf.data` which is a game-changer in my opinion.

**EDIT**

I attended a talk by Chollet on TF2 (couldn't find a recording online) in which he basically said that support for frameworks other than TF would eventually drop and future developments of Keras would happen exclusively in `tf.keras`.

From what I can see, this is already happening, as [Keras' commit stream](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commits/master/docs) is getting thin these days.

It makes a lot of sense since, as of now, the only other popular DL framework is pytorch, which is not supported by Keras. Keeping Keras code "agnostic" to tensorflow -- the only major framework it is supporting -- makes less and less sense.

So today, my answer would be to use `tf.keras` by default, and keep Keras for legacy projects that would be hard to migrate -- that is the future-proof choice for Keras.

Comment: `tf.data which is a game-changer in my opinion` - could you further elaborate on this?

Comment: Is there any insight now which Keras (Keras vs tf.Keras) can run on TPUs in Google Colab? I was using Keras and set the Runtime Settings to TPU yet it was obviously running on CPUs

Comment: @saurabheights The `tf.data` pipeline in tensorflow is an underrated jewel. It allows you to write your own data loader and augmentations with standard tensorflow operations, and it will run very efficiently in parallel to your graph execution on GPU. AFAIK no other framework offers this blend of efficiency, flexibility and simplicity.

Answer (score 12):

> Keras is best understood as an API specification, not as a specific
>   codebase. In fact, going fowards there will be two separate
>   implementations of the Keras spec: the internal TensorFlow one,
>   available as tf.keras, written in pure TensorFlow and deeply
>   compatible with all TensorFlow functionality, and the external
>   multi-backend one supporting both Theano and TensorFlow (and likely
>   even more backends in the future).

https://blog.keras.io/introducing-keras-2.html

Answer (score 1):

Recent François Chollet [tweet](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174018651449544704?s=19) suggests to use **tf.keras**.

> We recommend you switch your Keras code to tf.keras.
>
> Both Theano and CNTK are out of development. Meanwhile, as Keras
>   backends, they represent less than 4% of Keras usage. The other 96% of
>   users (of which more than half are already on tf.keras) are better
>   served with tf.keras.
>
> Keras development will focus on tf.keras going forward.
>
> Importantly, we will seek to start developing tf.keras in its own
>   standalone GitHub repository at keras-team/keras in order to make it
>   much easier for 3rd party folks to contribute.