# Tensorflow creating new variables despite reuse set to true

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a basic RNN, but I get errors trying to use the network after training.
I hold network architecture in a function `inference`

```
def inference(inp):
    with tf.name_scope("inference"):
        layer = SimpleRNN(1, activation='sigmoid',   return_sequences=False)(inp)
        layer = Dense(1)(layer)

    return layer
```

but everytime i call it, another set of variables gets created despite using the same scope in training:

```
def train(sess, seq_len=2, epochs=100):
    x_input, y_input = generate_data(seq_len)

    with tf.name_scope('train_input'):
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, seq_len, 1))
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 1))

    with tf.variable_scope('RNN'):
        output = inference(x)

    with tf.name_scope('training'):
        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=output)
        train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    with sess.as_default():
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])

        for i in tqdm.trange(epochs):
            ls, res, _ = sess.run([loss, output, train_op], feed_dict={x:x_input, y:y_input})
            if i%100==0:
                print(f'{ls}: {res[10]} - {y_input[10]}')
            x_input, y_input = generate_data(seq_len)
```

and prediction:

```
def predict_signal(sess, x, seq_len):   
    # Preparing signal (omitted)
    # Predict
    inp = tf.convert_to_tensor(prepared_signal, tf.float32)
    with sess.as_default():
        with tf.variable_scope('RNN', reuse=True) as scope:
            output = inference(inp)
            result = output.eval()

    return result
```

I have spent couple of hours reading about variables scopes by now, but on running prediction I still get an error `Attempting to use uninitialized value RNN_1/inference/simple_rnn_2/kernel`, with the number by RNN_1 increasing with each call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just speculation until you show us the `SimpleRNN` implementation. However, I suspect that `SimpleRNN` is very badly implemented. There is a different getween `tf.get_variable` and `tf.Variable`. I expect your `SimpleRNN` to use `tf.Variable`.

To reproduce this behaviour:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def inference(x):
    w = tf.Variable(1., name='w')
    layer = x + w
    return layer


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope('RNN'):
    output = inference(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(output, {x: 10}))

    with sess.as_default():
        with tf.variable_scope('RNN', reuse=True):
            output2 = inference(x)

    print(sess.run(output2, {x: 10}))
```

This gives exactly the same error:

> Attempting to use uninitialized value RNN_1/w

However the version with `w = tf.get_variable('w', initializer=1.)` instead of `w = tf.Variable(1., name='w')` makes it work.

Why? See the docs:

[`tf.get_variable:`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/get_variable)

> Gets an existing variable with these parameters or create a new one.
>   This function prefixes the name with the current variable scope and performs **reuse checks**.

**edit**
Thank you for the question (I added the keras flag to your question). This is now becoming my favorite reason to show people why using Keras is the worst decision they ever made.

SimpleRNN [creates it variables here:](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/468f080c98f06780c950e5a78c9eeeaf9fff002e/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L826-L830)

```
self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      name='kernel',...)
```

This [executes the line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/468f080c98f06780c950e5a78c9eeeaf9fff002e/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L249-L252)

```
weight = K.variable(initializer(shape),
                    dtype=dtype,
                    name=name,
                    constraint=constraint)
```

which [ends up here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/468f080c98f06780c950e5a78c9eeeaf9fff002e/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L399)

```
v = tf.Variable(value, dtype=tf.as_dtype(dtype), name=name)
```

And this is an obvious flaw in the implementation.
Until Keras uses TensorFlow in the correct way (respecting at least `scopes` and `variable-collections`), you should look for alternatives. The best advice somebody can give you is to switch to something better like the official `tf.layers`.

Comment: I use SimpleRNN implementation from Keras

Comment: There are too many issues with keras. Keras does **not** respect `scopes` and `collection` breaking all common assumptions of TensorFlow. The best advice somebody can give you is stick with the official `tf.layers`. And now Keras-Fanboys let the downvotes begin.

Comment: great observation @Patwie! i encountered some weird behavior from the keras simpleRNN trying to solve a rather simple task.
posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396482/exact-model-converges-on-keras-tf-but-not-on-keras).
i believe it happens due to this implementation fault.
switching to keras-tf seems to solve it.
just wanted to make your point stronger, i now firmly believe that if you use tensorflow, go for the keras implemented specifically for it, and not the general one.

Answer (score 1):

@Patwie made the correct diagnosis regarding the error — a possible bug in the reference Keras implementation.

However, in my opinion, the logical conclusion is not to dismiss Keras, but to use the Keras implementation that comes with tensorflow, that can be found in `tf.keras`. You will find that variables are generated correctly in this implementation. `tf.keras` is implemented specifically for tensorflow and should minimize this kind of interfacing error.

In fact, if you are already tensorflow, I don't see any particular benefit in using the reference Keras rather than `tf.keras`, unless you are using its very latest features, `tf.keras` being typically a bit behind in terms of versions (e.g. currently at 2.1.5 in TF 1.8 wheras Keras 2.2.0 has been out for about a month).

Comment: Havent't tested tf.keras. But a quick look at the implementation indicates there is much more logic involved in `add_weight`. Upvote here from my side for suggesting tf.keras instead Keras (I thought they supposed to be the same.) But if this helps, why not.