# Typecasting error in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, type-conversion

Suppose I am implementing a linear layer on some training data that looks like
 [image]

The following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

weights = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, 3))
bias = tf.Variable(0.0)
trainingData = np.array(np.arange(15).astype(float).reshape(3,5))
output = tf.expand_dims(weights, 0) @ trainingData + bias
```

produces

[image]

This can be fixed by instead changing the last line to say

```
tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(weights, 0) @ trainingData, tf.float32) + bias
```

OK, so it doesn't like adding a `float32_ref` to a `float64,` but it's OK with adding a `float32_ref` to a `float32.` But I must be doing something wrong, because I'm doing something very simple, and it's throwing an error. (I'm new to TensorFlow.) I understand why it didn't like what I wrote, but what basic mistake am I making that's causing this problem?

I'm looking for an answer like "Oh, you should never initialize bias with a float like 0.0, because..." "That will lead to typecasting errors more generally."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Oh, you should never* use `tf.Variable` unless you have a very good reason. You should use `tf.get_variable` instead to avoid [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51167542/7443104).
2. *Oh, you should never* use float64 as the data type, unless you do have a good reason. NumPy uses float64 as a default, so you should write something like

   ```
   W = tf.get_variable("w", initializer=np.random.randn().astype(np.float32))
   ```

Comment: So don't use float64, because things like this will happen? Any other reason not to use float64?

Comment: Looking at the [specs](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/tesla-v100/) about tera-flops for single precision vs double precision. Also see this [explanation](https://arrayfire.com/explaining-fp64-performance-on-gpus/).