# Reseting the graph in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tensor

I have a block that creates an LSTM Model for me. I want to iterate on this block and every time pass a new data to it as an arg. but it raises this error :

```
ValueError: Variable rnn/lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

I googled it and I found out that by resetting the model by using this piece of code at the beginning of the block I can solve the error:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

but it raises another error:

```
ValueError: Tensor("lstm/rnn/Const:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32).
```

what should I do now?
thanks a lot

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616625/valueerror-tensor-must-be-from-the-same-graph-as-tensor-with-bidirectinal-rnn-i)?

Comment: yes I didn't use "with tf.Graph().as_default()" @skrubber

Comment: You should use different name args within the loop. Or are we talking about [Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167542/tensorflow-creating-new-variables-despite-reuse-set-to-true/51167774#51167774)? Why not providing a [mcve]?